# Linked folder not resolved by Ant in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

In my build.xml, below works fine :-

```
<path id="build.classpath">
        <fileset dir="lib [myUtils]" includes="*.jar" />
</path>
```

if **lib [myUtils]** is of **folder** type, but don't works, if it's of **Linked Folder** type.

---

Also, I found this when googled :-

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=265960

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=43081

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=265960

---

Is there any trick to achieve this, without copying the dependencies in work folder??

Comment: I always found Eclipse funny.

Answer (score 0):

Note that ant should work outside of eclipse as well. So you can't reply in IDE abstractions. You can use symbolic links (if your OS supports them).

If not, you can use the [FileSync](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/index.html) plugin to synchronize eclipse project folders with external folders. Or you can simply use the `<copy>` ant task.

Comment: but, I am working on MS Win XP. Is there any hack available for that.

Comment: no, there isn't anything clean. Check my update for some sort of a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this using copy task:

```
<copy todir="target/web/linked1">
    <fileset dir="../linkdProject/source1" />
</copy>
<copy todir="target/web/linked2">
    <fileset dir="../linkedProject/source2" />
</copy>
....
<war destfile="target/webApp.war">
    <fileset dir="WebContent" />
    <fileset dir="target/web" /> <!-- copy linked resources -->
    ...
</war>
<delete dir="target"/>
```